# Get Total Count from Current Status Query MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-connection

I have problem to count total data on current status on mysql query.

Briefly, i have 3 tables that relate each other.

```
m_shift_schedule     site_shift_schedule      m_ticket
================     ===================     ============
* shift_id   ======>  * shift_id             * ticket_id
* start_time          * shift_date           * ticket_status
* end_time            * user_id   ========>  * ticket_served_by
```

My query:

```
SELECT user_id,
case when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)<2 then 'idle' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)=2 then 'Busy' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)>2 then 'Overload' end as status
FROM site_shift_schedule
LEFT JOIN m_shift_schedule ON site_shift_schedule.shift_id = m_shift_schedule.shift_id
LEFT JOIN m_ticket ON site_shift_schedule.user_id=m_ticket.ticket_served_by
WHERE site_shift_schedule.shift_date =  '2019-02-11' and m_ticket.ticket_status in (4,5,6)
AND CURRENT_TIME > start_time and CURRENT_TIME < end_time
group by user_id
```

My output from query above:

```
user_id                           Status
=============================   ============
ismail.rahman.saanin@random.co     Idle
lutfi.aldi.nugroho@random.co       Busy
```

And the question, What should i do if i want show the output become like this:

```
 Status              Total
==================================
 Idle                 1
 Busy                 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - using subquery

```
select status,count(user_id) as total
from
(
SELECT user_id,
case when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)<2 then 'idle' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)=2 then 'Busy' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)>2 then 'Overload' end as status
FROM site_shift_schedule
LEFT JOIN m_shift_schedule ON site_shift_schedule.shift_id = m_shift_schedule.shift_id
LEFT JOIN m_ticket ON site_shift_schedule.user_id=m_ticket.ticket_served_by
WHERE site_shift_schedule.shift_date =  '2019-02-11' and m_ticket.ticket_status in (4,5,6)
AND CURRENT_TIME > start_time and CURRENT_TIME < end_time
group by user_id
)A group by status
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when also in `group by`

```
SELECT 
case when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)<2 then 'idle' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)=2 then 'Busy' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)>2 then 'Overload' end as status,
     count(*) as total
FROM site_shift_schedule
LEFT JOIN m_shift_schedule ON site_shift_schedule.shift_id = m_shift_schedule.shift_id
LEFT JOIN m_ticket ON site_shift_schedule.user_id=m_ticket.ticket_served_by
WHERE site_shift_schedule.shift_date =  '2019-02-11' and m_ticket.ticket_status in (4,5,6)
AND CURRENT_TIME > start_time and CURRENT_TIME < end_time
group by  case when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)<2 then 'idle' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)=2 then 'Busy' 
     when count(m_ticket.ticket_served_by)>2 then 'Overload' end
```

Comment: May you share the fiddle as I don't think it will work because of missing `user_id` from `group by` clause.

Comment: @aldi have you checked it ?